# Limit problem. L'Hospital's Rule not allowed.

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm lost on the following problem. I don't know which method to use.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin({\frac{2}{x}})+\frac{2}{x}}{\sin({\frac{1}{x}})}$$

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{t\to 0} \sin(t)/t = 1$? Now make $t=1/x$ and note that $x\to +\infty$ if and only if $t\to 0^+$. Good luck!

Comment: Since $x\to\infty$, the arguments of the sines tend to 0; one can possibly approximate the sines by their Taylor expansion to the first term.

Comment: When you can't use L'Hopital the trick is *always* without fail to multiply and divide by new terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the limit without using a double-angle identity:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(2/x)+2/x}{\sin(1/x)}&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(2t)+2t}{\sin(t)}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\left[\frac{\sin(2t)}{\sin(t)}+2\frac{t}{\sin(t)}\right]\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\left[\frac{\sin(2t)}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(t)}+2\frac{t}{\sin(t)}\right]\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\left[\frac{\sin(2t)}{2t}\cdot\frac{2t}{\sin(t)}+2\frac{t}{\sin(t)}\right]\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(2t)}{2t}\cdot2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{\sin(t)}+2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{\sin(t)}\\
&=1\cdot2+2\\
&=4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin({\frac{2}{x}})+\frac{2}{x}}{\sin({\frac{1}{x}})} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin(2y)+2y}{\sin(y)} =  \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{2\sin(y)\cos(y)+2y}{\sin(y)} \\=  2\lim_{y \to 0}\cos(y) + 2  \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{y}{\sin(y)}$$
We have $\lim_{y \to 0}\cos(y) = 1$ and $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin(y) - \sin(0)}{y-0} = \sin'(0) = \cos(0) = 1$, thus your limit is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two keys to this problem.  I won't provide a full solution, but I will leave the tools below as hints:

1. As @IvoTerek mentioned, $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t} = 1$.  So making the substitution $t=1/x$ gets you part of the way there.
2. The other hint is that $\sin(2t)=2\sin(t)\cos(t)$.  This identity will be needed to complete the problem.

Good luck!